# group rows by index using linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to group rows by index using LINQ in c#

for example, I have collection like this:

- John, Ready, 13.44, John
- Jason, Ready, 2.5, Eric
- Mary, Active, 3, Rose
- Mary, Active, 3, Antony

And I'd like to group the result by Collection[3] and concatenates the result using '|', so the expected result is:

- John, Ready, 13.44, John
- Jason, Ready, 2.5, Eric
- Mary, Active, 3, Rose | Antony

How can I implement?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "by index" here - what are the first two columns, and is it just *coincidence* that those are the same for the two active names? Also, what have you tried so far? `GroupBy` is an obvious choice, for example.

Comment: Keep in mind that we have no idea how your data looks. `I have collection like this` might mean that you have collection of strings or collection of predefined objects or collection of anonymous objects. Question is very vague and shows literally zero research effort. Not to say anything about no understanding of problem.

Answer (score 1):

making some assumptions about row structure:

```
rows
    .GroupBy(r => new {r.Name,r.Status,r.Value})
    .Select(g => new{g.Key.Name,g.Key.Status,g.Key.Value, g.Aggregate(string.Empty, (s,r) => s + 
            '|' + r.Name2)})
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the items are in ListObject. Find the below code to group the items

`List<NewObj> = ListObject.GroupBy(x => x.colum1)` for single column

`List<NewObj> = ListObject.GroupBy(x => new { x.colum1, x.colum2 })` for multiple column group.